# Cordova file-transfer plugin: cannot insert request headers Android

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, download, file-transfer

I am using cordova file-transfer plugin version 1.3.0  to download a file from a Web Api server on my android device;
I'm trying to send headers (i.e. Accept and a few custom headers), but if
I check the request on server with a sniffer (like wireshark), my
headers are not there.

I'm using phonegap build (cli 5.2.2) to build apk;
my device is a Samsung GT-S7500 (Android 2.3.6 gingerbread);
in config.xml I set whitelist and include plugin (I tried both specifying  version number (1.3.0) and without it);

this is my code (called in DeviceReady event handler)

```
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

    fileTransfer.download(attachUri, fileURL,
        function (entry) {
            debug.log("ERROR","download complete: " + entry.toURL());
            window.open(entry.toNativeURL(), '_blank',   'location=no,closebuttoncaption=Close,enableViewportScale=yes');
        },
        function (error) {
            alert("Error:" + error);
            debug.log("ERROR",error);
        }),
        false,
        {
            headers:{
                "Accept":"application/octet-stream",
                "Authorization": "Basic   dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
            }
        };
```

this are the headers received by web api server

```
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Accept-Encoding: gzip
  Host: 192.168.0.10
  User-Agent: Dalvik/1.4.0
  User-Agent: (Linux; U; Android 2.3.6; GT-S7500 Build/GINGERBREAD)
```

on Github a bug similar to this seems that was fixed on release 1.3.0. but it doesn't work in my case.

Any help?

**EDIT: this is my config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <widget id="com.phonegap.AsxMobApp" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
        <name>AsxMobApp</name>
        <description>
            AsxMobApp
        </description>
        <author>
            AsxMobApp Team
        </author>
        <content src="index.html" />
        <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
        <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
        <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
        <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
        <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
        <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
        <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
        <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
        <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
        <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
        <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
        <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
        <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />
        <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
        <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />

        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" source="npm" />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" source="pgb" version="0.3.6" />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" source="npm" />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" source="npm" />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" source="npm" />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" source="npm" />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" source="npm" />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" source="npm" />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" source="npm" />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" source="npm" />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" source="npm" />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" source="npm" />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" source="npm" />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" source="npm" version="0.2.3" />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" source="npm" />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" source="npm" />
        <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" />
        <!-- file-transfer: questo plugin permette di scaricare in locale dei file da specifici url -->
        <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" />
        <!-- whitelist: questo plugin permette di configurare i domini a cui l'applicazione può accedere via http, https ecc.
             serve per far funzionare il plugin filetransfer che permette di scaricare in locale dei file da un determinato url (nel nostro caso gli allegati di una mail) -->
        <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1.0.0" source = "npm"/>

        <icon src="icon.png" />
        <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
        <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
        <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
        <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
        <icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
        <icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
        <icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
        <icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon gap:platform="webos" src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
        <icon gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
        <icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" />
        <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
        <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
        <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
        <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
        <gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" />
        <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
        <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
        <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1136" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" width="640" />
        <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
        <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
        <gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />


        <!-- allow-navigation questa configurazione dice al plugin whitelist che tutti i domini possono essere contattati; in questo modo si riesce a far funzionare il plugin filetransfer che permette di scaricare in locale un file da un URL (nel nostro caso per il download in locale degli allegati -->
        <allow-navigation href="*" />
        <allow-intent href="*" />
        <access origin="*" /> <!-- Required for iOS9 -->

        <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
        <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
        <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
        <platform name="android">
            <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        </platform>
        <platform name="ios">
            <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
            <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        </platform>
        <engine name="android" spec="~4.1.1" />
    </widget>
```

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#File

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.

I have removed, icons, splashes, some preferences, etc. This is stuff you can put back.

- I have set your compiler version to `cli-5.2.0`.
- I have set your android-minSdkVersion to `14`. This is because you are using Gingerbread. The compiler SHOULD set to that value, but I want to make sure your device works.
- I have included some plugins; those you had versions for.
- I have include only `file-transfer`; `file-transfer` installs the version of `file` that it needs. (`file` in comments, just in case.) If you have problems, with this I will be up for another 1/2 hour.
- I've installed the `whitelist` plugin; make sure you put in the `CSP` in your `index.html`.

*Please read the [**Phonegap Build blog**](http://phonegap.com/blog/phonegap-build) for the last 60 days, and expect more changes in the next 30 days.*

**READ the bold lines**
[Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

### NOTE YOUR APP IS NOW INSECURE. IT IS UP TO YOU TO SECURE YOUR APP.

[HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <widget id="com.phonegap.AsxMobApp" 
        version="1.0.0" 
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
         xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
        <name>AsxMobApp</name>
        <description>AsxMobApp</description>
        <author>AsxMobApp Team</author>
        <preference name="phonegap-version"      value="cli-5.2.0" />
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />

        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera"         source="npm" spec="1.2.0" />
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="1.0.1" />
        <!-- <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file"           source="npm" spec="2.1.0" /> -->
        <!-- file-transfer: questo plugin permette di scaricare in locale dei file da specifici url -->
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" spec="1.2.0" />
        <!-- whitelist: questo plugin permette di configurare i domini a cui l'applicazione può accedere via http, https ecc.
             serve per far funzionare il plugin filetransfer che permette di scaricare in locale dei file da un determinato url (nel nostro caso gli allegati di una mail) -->
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist"      source="npm" spec="1.1.0" />

        <!-- allow-navigation questa configurazione dice al plugin whitelist che tutti i domini possono essere contattati; in questo modo si riesce a far funzionare il plugin filetransfer che permette di scaricare in locale un file da un URL (nel nostro caso per il download in locale degli allegati -->
        <allow-navigation href="*" />
        <allow-intent href="*" />
        <access origin="*" /> <!-- Required for iOS9 -->
    </widget>
```

### NOTE YOUR APP IS NOW INSECURE. IT IS UP TO YOU TO SECURE YOUR APP.

[HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)

Comment: Thank you Jesse, I'll try it asap, and I'll come back with the result.

Comment: @ Jesse Hi, I finally found the error; in the first post, in the method fileTransfer.download ( ) there is a closing parenthesis  in the wrong place; just before the 'trustAllHosts' parameter, instead of after the 'option' (headers) parameter. Sorry for wasting your time and thank you for all your suggestions: they were precious.

Comment: Precious, I feel like a [pomeranian](http://thedogwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Pomeranian-Puppies-768x1024.jpg). Glad to hear you got it working. That's the most important part. Best of Luck.

Answer (score 0):

@elena,
As of Cordova 5.0.0, you are required to use the `whitelist` system.
The `whitelist system` has 5 sections which makes it difficult for even well-seasoned developers.

You will need to add a section to your 1) `config.xml` and add a line to your 2) `index.html`.

1) Add to your `config.xml`

`<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" /> <!-- Required for iOS9 -->`

2) add to yoour `index.html`

 `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
          content="default-src *; 
                   style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
                   script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">`

### NOTE: YOUR APP IS NOW INSECURE.

### IT IS UP TO YOU TO SECURE YOUR APP.

Please see the link that follows to assist you in securing your app.
[HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)
Best of Luck

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you for your suggestions.
The settings in section 1 were already set in config.xml; I added those related to point 2, in the index.html file, but nothing has changed; any other ideas?

Comment: Post your config.xml. I suspect the changes may conflict with something else you have in the file. In the original post please, and make sure to message me when done - so I can see the updates. TIA

Comment: Hi JesseMonroy650, I've added config.xml in the original post. Thank you.

Comment: @elena, you have a big problem. ARE YOU USING [*Phonegap Build*](https://build.phonegap.com/), the cloud base service by Adobe.? Otherwise, your `config.xml` is way off. I say this because NONE of your tags state you want help with `phonegap-build`

Comment: @Jessse yes, I'm using  [link](https://build.phonegap.com) _italic_Phonegap Build! My appication works fine, both on Chrome ( using ripple ), both on my device (Samsung Galaxy GT-S7500, Android 2.3.6 Gingerbread); the only problem is that using plugin file-transfer to download file, file are downloaded, but no headers sended; I need to send custom headers to authenticate users!

Comment: Hi Jesse, sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow, so in my comment there are some mistakes...sorry for my english too.

Comment: Okay. First, there is a tag `phonegap-build`. Use it. Second, you have errors in your `config.xml`. I am going to fix them, and post the fixes. Third, stated on the nitobi forum, that *file* and *file-transfer* plugins need to be pinned to a version, else the conflict. If still have problems, try a lower verison, but I should be giving you what you need. I will be about 20 minutes.